# Pytest Logging messages appear twice

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, pytest

My testing framework has below structure

- Master_test_Class.py ---> Holds generic test cases to be run for smoke and regression test suite
- Test_Smoke1.py and Test_Reg1.py --> Child classes inherit Master_test_class.py

[image]

I have logging enabled in pytest.ini for INFO

```
[pytest]
log_cli = 1 
log_cli_level = INFO
```

Below is my code in conftest.py

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
.....
logging.info("This is generated during the test collection !!!")
```

When i run the test either of the test files, logs are printed 2 times once in the formatting specified in pytest.ini and another in red color

```
pytest -s Test_Reg1.py
```

[image]

I am so lost why is the logging info getting printed twice.

Comment: please share logger configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see only the output of logging module, use `--log-cli-level=INFO` as an argument to pytest test run. You are seeing it twice because of `-s` switch. And, to test whether it's the same log or different, add timestamp to the log message.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you have a logging handler that sends the logs to the standard output, the solution would be, either run `pytest` without argument `-s` (this assumes logs have all the information you need) or remove the logging handler that is using standard output.